# Problem with LDAP: ldapindex

Tags: debian, ldap, openldap

I'm installing ldap server on debian machine. Here is the link to the guide I am following:

http://www.debian-administration.org/article/OpenLDAP_installation_on_Debian

I installed all the needed packages and edited all the neccessary config files.

```
sudo invoke-rc.d slapd stop
sudo slapindex
sudo chown openldap:openldap /var/lib/ldap/*
sudo invoke-rc.d slapd start
```

But when I try to restart server with newly added options I got this warning:

```
WARNING!
Runnig as root!
There's a fair chance slapd will fail to start.
Check file permissions!
```

I searched for it and found a bug report here: bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=432662

So I tried to run the command to execute ldapindex as openldap user and it seemed to work nicely, but ldap did not saved my new configs.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is the /var/lib/ldap directory itself owned by openldap:openldap? In your example you only changed the contents of the directory, not the directory itself ... :-)

Comment: And why are you trying to run slapd as root? Does the init script really tell it to do so or have you altered some config files?

Comment: @Janne Pikkarainen: slapd runs as root by default.

Comment: @Janne Pikkarainen: I think the problem is the the ldap config file, not the lib directory... But I'm not sure. I tested different combinations but nothing works. I also downloaded the src and tryed to compile it, but got the same error.

Comment: @Rizo: Does it? At least on my Debian Lenny it runs as openldap user. Although it _might_ be that I have configured the slapd.conf looooong time ago ... :-)

Comment: @Janne Pikkarainen: You're right! LDAP server should be run by openldap user and slapd.conf file has to have friendly permissions, but it has not by default -- that's the bug.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember from our LDAP install (long time ago), you should edit the /etc/default/slapd and add the following:

```
SLAPD_USER="openldap"
SLAPD_GROUP="openldap"
```

and then restart your server.

Hope it helps!